# Get element via jQuery quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fetch the radio input element object.

In this approach, if the page is huge with many radio inputs, then it will take time to iterate over them before returning the object.

Is there a faster approach to get input object other than this? The condition is that the value should start with text '9Z'.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" value="9Z>2">
        </td>
    </div>

    <script>
        var r = $("input:radio[value^='9Z']");
        alert(r.length); //I got the object - length will be greater than 0
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it's possible, give that element a unique ID and select it with that.

Comment: don't use :radio, it's a jquery specific selector and will be very slow with a large number of elements.

Comment: No, it is not possible. The html data is not designed by me.

Comment: @KevinB can you please demonstrate how by small example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:radio` is a jquery specific selector, therefore by using it, you're not allowing jquery to use the quicker `document.querySelectorAll()` method. Simply replace it with the attribute equals selector.

```
$("input[type=radio][value^='9Z']")
```

If that still isn't fast enough, we'll need to know more about the structure of your page.

You could also do this for a very small increase (no IE7 support):

```
$(document.querySelector("input[type=radio][value^='9Z']"))
```